# numpy module not found error: downloaded it twice through cmd, maybe because of two version of python in my system

Tags: python, numpy, cmd, pip

while i tried importing numpy module, error "NO MODULE NAMED NUMPY", occurs. Even after downloading the numypy module through cmd(pip), the same error occurs. I guess it is because i have installed two versions of python in my system. How should I fix that?[1][This is the error which occurs again and again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3e0y.png)[This is my python code with the statement - `import numpy as np`]

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File C:\Users\RAJEEV SHARMA\Desktop\synonpsis and code\olympicspyile.py.py",
 line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add PATH while installing?

May take a look at the Linux subsystem for Windows, that will make it easier... [what Windows says about installing Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/beginners)

Comment: no i did'nt, because in our book its not mentioned, can u pls tell me how to go about it

Comment: at the initial installing screen you have some options, take your time and read thouse.